# How to change vim tab pages in tmux

Tags: vim, terminal, tmux

So using vim in terminal, I can use ctrl+pgdown, ctrl+pgup to navigate between vim tab pages. However I lose these keybindings if I open the files inside tmux.

What is the command to do this inside tmux?

Comment: Please provide more info about tmux and vim versions

Answer (score 5):

You can use vim's standard `gt` and `gT` mappings for changing next/prev tab.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However I've always found gt and gT a bit inconsistent. Can I somehow bind other keys for these command?

Comment: @MattSom maybe we could fix `ctrl+pagup[down]` bindings, if you provide more info on what version of vim and tmux you are using. Also pasting your .tmux.conf and .vimrc will help as well if there are any remappings. Because `ctrl+pagup[down]` are working for me I use neovim 0.2.0 and tmux 2.4